# What happened to /usr/include/machine directory in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to build/compile a old project using the original makefile. When I do so, I get the following error:

```
 *** No rule to make target `/usr/include/machine/param.h'
```

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04. There seem to be plenty of param.h files, but no /usr/include/machine directory. Does anyone know which (if any) of the existing param.h files I should use ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't recall a `/usr/include/machine/` directory before... but that said, try `/usr/include/linux/param.h`.